# Functional Data Analysis with Missing Data

Tags: r, missing-data, smoothing, functional-data-analysis

I am trying to analyze a dataset containing several observations for n = 27. Unfortunately, not every participant answered the question every time, i.e., when plotting the graph it has holes in it. I am trying to provide an analysis of the mean and variance across those functions. For this, I have to smooth them. I can smooth each one separately with excluding NAs. Now, I'm either looking for a better way to smooth them so they each have the same length or a way to re-align them along the time points of the original data and not some landmarks. Does anyone here have an idea how to accomplish that? I can provide the smoothing code I have so far if necessary (fyi I'm using the fda package in R).

Comment: If the data are on a pre-specified grid they are longitudinal rather than functional, so in that sense there is less grounds for a smoothness assumption to be expected. Is there a reason why wouldn't you use a (G)LME model at first instance?

Comment: I want to research the difference in handling those data as time series compared to functional data analysis

Comment: Have you looked at Yao et al. (2005)? Effectively they have pooling estimates that work as long as we have $n \geq 2$ measurements per subject ($n=1$ just helps with the variance not the covariance estimation).